# HCS geo HMS slope calculation issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, hec-geohms

I am using slope function from geoHMS Toolkit in arcMap 10.3. After the execution of the function the river attribute table is showing 0 in all the fields of slope,ElevUP  and Elev down. I am projecting the river with same coordinates as rawDem.

I am attaching the attribute table and projection of the river(stream).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually this happened to me too. I think the problem is using rawDEM. The automatically generated rawDEM data is not the same as the original input raster but it should be. After I checked the rawDEM, I found out the rawDEM actually is basin-averaged raster (or I am not exactly sure what it is). So when calculating the slope, I manually choose the input DEM instead of rawDEM.